# Is there any other purpose for boss souls in Dark Souls 2?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I'm wondering if there is any other purpose to boss souls in Dark Souls 2. I already know about Straid and Ornifex providing weapons/spells/armor in exchange, as well as the aspect of getting a lot of souls for using the souls.

As a primary caster, I don't need the weapons, so I'm planing on consuming all souls except the ones tradable for spells.

**Are there any other purposes for boss souls than getting weapons/armor/spells and acquiring souls?**

Comment: There are a lot of worse first questions. ;) Does this help you? http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Boss+Souls

Comment: @Fabian; Thanks. The Link you provided is just a list of the spells/equip provided by Straid/Ornifex. I already knew this. I heard somewhere, that you get a new sassy hat, if you trade four souls to Straid. I hoped for confirmation on this or other information like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by @Fabian the weapons he linked are all the weapons/spells you can get.

However you also have the option to get unique items if you give multiple boss souls

[Straid](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Straid+of+Olaphis)

> Talk to him after trading 4 boss souls and he will give you the Black Robe Set, which requires at least 16 Int to equip. The hood boosts your spell casting speed.

[Weaponsmith Ornifex](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Weaponsmith+Ornifex) sadly doesn't house the same option.

Comment: So, that's all?

Comment: @Jannoire yes, other than mass amounts of souls when consumed, obviously

Answer (score 5):

[Soul of a Giant](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/soul-of-a-giant) can be used to make one of boss fights easier:

> The more Souls of a Giant you have in your inventory, the less damage resistance King Vendrick has.

However, this soul is not strictly 'boss soul'. But it still drops from one of bosses.